# Android STICKY Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarm

I try to create an Alarm app, I create a WakefulBroadcastReceiver where onRecive method I have:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("onRecive Alarm broadcast");

        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
```

while my Alarm service is this:

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long millisec = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        sendNotification("Messaggio della notifica");

        System.out.println("onHandleIntent: " + getDate(millisec,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));


        AlarmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

if I don't kill my app all work as expected, but if I close the app the service is never fired.
Where is the error? 
On my manifest I've added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "close the app"?

Comment: removed from multitasking (on a huawei rom when you click the bin on multitasking)